# Typescript functions return type is not captured

Tags: typescript

What am I missing here, `result` is of type `{foo: unknown, bar: unknown, baz: unknown}`
I think it should be of type `{foo: number, bar: boolean, baz: string}`

```
export function apply<A, B extends {[P in keyof A]: B[P]}>(
  functions: {[P in keyof A]: (a: A[P]) => B[P]},
  data: {[P in keyof A]: A[P]},
): {[P in keyof A]: B[P]} {
  const result = {} as {[P in keyof A]: B[P]}
  const keys = Object.keys(functions) as (keyof A)[]
  for(const key of keys)
    result[key] = functions[key](data[key])
  return result
}

const functions = {
  foo: (a: string) => a.length,
  bar: (a: number) => a === 42,
  baz: (a: boolean) => a ? 'true' : 'false'
}
const data = {foo: 'foo', bar: 42, baz: true}
const result = apply(functions, data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let's examine the issues with the current attempt, namely the types you've given to the two arguments.

```
functions: {[P in keyof A]: (a: A[P]) => B[P]},
data: {[P in keyof A]: A[P]}
```

Looks like you want the type `A[P]` to represent the value types of the `A` object. The problem here is that there are no restrictions on the type `A`, so there is nothing we can use to infer a more specific type for the values. Thus they are inferred to have the most general type: `unknown`.

Consider that you can manually specify generic parameters when you invoke the `apply` function. Something like:

```
type A = {} // ??? what to put here?
type B = {} // ??? what to put here?
const result = apply<A, B>(functions, data)
```

The problem is I am not sure what I would give as the `A` type in this example. Indeed I'm not sure that a valid type for `A` even exists in this construction, other than what you've seen: `{foo: unknown, bar: unknown, baz: unknown}`.

---

So instead of using a mapped type for the arguments like above, why not add these restrictions to the generic signature itself? It looks like you want the `functions` parameter to be an object holding single argument functions. Let's restrict the generic `A` to meet that condition right away:

```
A extends Record<string, (a: any) => any>
```

And for `B`, this is the type of your data, it should match to the argument type of each corresponding function in `A`. We can also apply that restriction within the generic signature:

```
B extends {[P in keyof A]: Parameters<A[P]>[0]}
```

And finally, for the return type, this is another object but instead of corresponding to the argument type of `A`, it is the return type:

```
{[P in keyof A]: ReturnType<A[P]>
```

Putting all that together:

```
function apply<A extends Record<string, (a: any) => any>, B extends {[P in keyof A]: Parameters<A[P]>[0]}>(
    functions: A,
    data: B
): {[P in keyof A]: ReturnType<A[P]> {
    const result = {} as {[P in keyof A]: B[P]}
    const keys = Object.keys(functions) as (keyof A)[]
    for(const key of keys)
        result[key] = functions[key](data[key])
    return result
}

const functions = {
    foo: (a: string) => a.length,
    bar: (a: number) => a === 42,
    baz: (a: boolean) => a ? 'true' : 'false'
}
const data = {foo: 'foo', bar: 42, baz: true}

const result = apply(functions, data)
// The type of `result` is inferred to be:
// {
//    foo: number;
//    bar: boolean;
//    baz: "true" | "false";
// }
```